# How to read a chosen value of HTML.RadioButtonFor in HTTPPOST?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, radiobuttonfor

I've read a lot of answers at SO, however it is not fit to me.

I have model:

```
class SomeOrder
{
     public string TypeDrink {get;  set;}
}
```

Controller:

```
public ViewResult Edit(int id)
{
  SomeOrder se = newSomeOrder{ TypeDrink=3 };
  return View(se);
}
```

And view:

```
@Html.EditorForModel   @Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.TypeDrink, "1") Tea
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.TypeDrink, "2") Coffee  
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.TypeDrink, "3") Juice
```

How to read a chosen value of radiobutton in a [HTTPPOST] method?
In my HTTPPOST method the preselected value is stored, not the chosen by user:

```
[HTTPPOST]
public ViewResult Edit(SomeOrder se) 
 {
   string chosenValue=se.TypeDrink;// always the old selected value
 }
```

Comment: If your POST method has parameter `SomeOrder model`, then `model.TypeDrink` will equal "1", "2" or "3" depending on which radio button you selected.

Comment: @StephenMuecke what am I doing wrong? I always get the old chosen value. I've added my HTTPPOST method to my question. Please, see my question

Comment: Nothing - if you select the first radio button then the value of `chosenValue` in the POST method will be `"1"`. Note I assume your real code in the GET method is actually `SomeOrder se = new SomeOrder{ TypeDrink = "3"  };`. If its not working its due to other issues you have not shown us, for example you have a hidden input for  the property before the radio buttons

Comment: @Stephen Muecke the reason was in @Html.EditorForModel(). This method writes HTML, however it was not shown at a page, I've seen just my three hand typed RadioButtonFor(). So hand typed RadioButtonFor couldn't overwrite values of Html.EditorForModel

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, please write your answer and I'll mark it:).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view includes `@Html.EditorForModel()` before your radio buttons. `EditorForModel()` will generate form controls for each property in your model so it will be generating a control for property `TypeDrink`. Depending on attributes applied to your property, and any `EditorTemplates` you may have, it may generated in a hidden input.

Because your form then posts back the name/pair values of the input generated by `EditorForModel` first, the value of the input will be bound to your model and the value of the radio buttons will be ignored by the `DefaultModelBinder`.

Remove the `EditorForModel` from your view and the model will be bound based on value of the radio buttons.

Answer (score 1):

if your post action is like

```
[HttPost]
public ViewResult Edit(SomeOrder model)
{
  // should get it like
  model.TypeDrink;
}
```

this is utilizing the model binding in mvc.

you could also look at the `Request.Form["TypeDrink"]` to get the value, but it is not recomended

Comment: what am I doing wrong? I always get the old chosen value. I've added my HTTPPOST method.

Answer (score 1):

Your Model is:

```
     using System;
     using System.Collections.Generic;
     using System.Linq;
     using System.Web;

     namespace radiotest.Models
     {
        public class SomeOrder
        {
            public string TypeDrink { get; set; }
        }
     }
```

**Your view is index.cshtml**

```
    @model radiotest.Models.SomeOrder

     @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
      }
     @using (Html.BeginForm())
     {
        <fieldset>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.TypeDrink, "1") Tea
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.TypeDrink, "2") Coffee
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.TypeDrink, "3") Juice
            </div>
            <div> <input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>
        </fieldset>

     }
```

Your Controller in HTTP Get and Post is:

```
    using radiotest.Models;
     using System;
     using System.Collections.Generic;
     using System.Linq;
     using System.Web;
     using System.Web.Mvc;

     namespace radiotest.Controllers
     {
        public class TestController : Controller
        {

            public ActionResu`enter code here`lt Index()
            {
                 SomeOrder se = new SomeOrder{ TypeDrink="3" };
                 return View(se);
            }

            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Index(SomeOrder model)
            {
                //model.TypeDrink gives you selected radio button in HTTP POST
                SomeOrder se = new SomeOrder {TypeDrink = model.TypeDrink };
                return View(se);
            }
        }
     }
```